# How to use zip command in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, zip

Suppose i have a zip file `Old.zip` , inside it are `fileA` and `fileB`. then i unzip them using: `unzip Old.zip -d Old`, then i will have a directory named Old, with fileA and fileB inside.

Now the Old.zip is gone, and i want to zip it again, but if i use: `zip -r New.zip Old`, the `New.zip` is different from `Old.zip`: inside it are not two files, but one directory!

```
Before:                 After:                        I want:
    Old.zip--+             New.zip--+                    New.zip--+
             +--fileA               +--Old--+                     +--fileA
             +--fileB                       +--fileA              +--fileB
                                            +--fileB
```

Any suggestions? How should i use zip command correctly to keep the structure? I will `NOT` go into `Old` folder and use `zip New.zip fileA fileB` and move it to the parent folder since i will write it in shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the the `-j` (junk paths) option to `zip`:

```
$ zip -rj New.zip Old
```

That way, the files will be stored without their relative paths.